# Background image on right and left side

Tags: html, css, css-float, background-image

How do I get this to work?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.left
{
float: left;
background-image: url('image_with_variable_width.png');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.right
{
float: right;
background-image: url('image_with_variable_width_flipped.png');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? It really depends on (a) what content is in each `<div>` and (b) how you ultimately want it to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the divs are empty, then nothing will appear because their height and width are zero. To make the background images appear, specify a height and width.

Comment: I don't know the width of the images

Comment: If the images are dynamic (as in, they change frequently and do not have consistent widths), then you can either set a fixed container width and manipulate the width of the background image using css: `background-size: 200px 50px` (only supported in CSS3), you can get the width using javascript and then set the width of the divs that way, or you can just have fixed column widths that are either larger or smaller than the images.

Comment: @Tyilo, if you really want to be clever, put an img tag that also has the image loaded with visibility: hidden;  It will take up the proper amount of space but won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Add height and width for your DIVs.